# Springboot @PathVariable value is including parenthesis

Tags: spring-boot, annotations

I am creating simple SpringBoot application. I declared PUT operation as follows

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.PUT, value= "/topics/{id}")
public void updateTopic(@PathVariable String id, Topic t){
    System.out.println("Kaushik==="+id);
    topicService.updateTopic(Integer.parseInt(id),t);
}
```

When I invoke PUT operation on URL `http://localhost:8080/topics/{2}`. It fails.
The value of variable id is "{2}" instead of simply "2" which is causing number format exception.

I also tried specifying parameter name. `public void updateTopic(@PathVariable(name="id") String id, Topic t){` but ut did not work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your decratation of the PUT endpoint is perfectly fine:

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.PUT, value= "/topics/{id}")
```

To call the URL simply use the desired value in place of `{id}`:

```
http://localhost:8080/topics/2
```

The URL template variable `{var}` is just an expression which marks part of the URL to be converted into the method parameter.

Comment: Ohh my god ..I must be foolish. I myself passing bracket and asking world where is it coming from. Thanks. I accept answer.